# Is there a more elegant/clean way to set HttpRequestMessage Headers using TryAddWithoutValidation method?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, http-method

I'm using HttpRequestMessage from HttpClient in a couple of methods and currently, I'm repeating the following piece of code all over my code:

This code was converted by https://curl.olsh.me/ so I'm not sure if best practices were used here.

```cs
// using System.Net.Http;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
 {
     using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://www.url.com/"))
                {
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("authority", "www.url.com");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("pragma", "no-cache");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("cache-control", "no-cache");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("dnt", "1");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-odesk-csrf-token", "19b91748869456a4ae700ffb69077745");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "*/*");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("origin", "https://www.url.com");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("sec-fetch-site", "same-origin");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("referer", "https://www.url.com/");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept-language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5");
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("cookie", "G_AUTHUSER_H=1; AccountSecurity_cat=fc4d14f1.oauth2v2_812293");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                    IEnumerable<string> cookies = new List<string>();
                    response.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out cookies);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really appreciate the answers from @Jaquez and @Kuroiyatsu, from both I get to the following

```
 public async Task<string> postAsync(param1, param2)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://www.url.com/"))
        {

....

var response = await PostAsync(param1, param2);

var variable = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Obj>(response);

WebScrapFunc(response);

...
```

Although it seems weird to return a `Task<string>` from PostAsync it fits fine my intents.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to understand how to extract the code in question into a helper method given its use of using blocks.  If not, please clarify and I will adjust my answer.  Here is what I would do in this case:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsyncWithHeaders(Uri uri)
{
    var response = new Task<HttpResponseMessage>();

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri))
    {
        //Add your headers as before

        response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }

    return response;
}
```

You can then call the method from anywhere it is accessible like this:

```
response = await PostAsyncWithHeaders(new Uri("https://www.url.com/"));

IEnumerable<string> cookies = new List<string>();
response.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out cookies);
//Presumably consume cookies (yum!)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this test in .NET Core 3 for reference.

If you want to be able to reuse your method throughout the code-base, you can try something like the following:

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // .NET core setting the content type.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        // this is wrapped in the using statement.
        using var requestMessage = GetRequestMessage("https://www.url.com/", HttpMethod.Post);
        await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    }

    // Get the request message for reuse. You can then reuse this for maybe different end-points and method types. 
    // the "referer" or "origin" values can be passed in as parameters too. 
    static HttpRequestMessage GetRequestMessage(string url, HttpMethod method)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);

        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("authority", "www.url.com");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("pragma", "no-cache");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("dnt", "1");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-odesk-csrf-token", "19b91748869456a4ae700ffb69077745");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "*/*");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("origin", "https://www.url.com");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("sec-fetch-site", "same-origin");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("referer", "https://www.url.com/");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept-language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("cookie", "G_AUTHUSER_H=1; AccountSecurity_cat=fc4d14f1.oauth2v2_812293");
        
        return request;
    }
```

If you are using this in a console program, you can be fine with creating HttpClient in a using statement. However, if you are intending to use the client in something like a web app in .net core, you want to use the services.AddHttpClient method and dependency injection. This is because the HttpClient isn't intended to be disposed of after every use, if you are using it multiple times in a given call especially.